# PayPal: Can you get the IP address of the client (buyer) via IPN/PDT?

Tags: paypal, ip-address, paypal-ipn, eclipse-pdt

I never found such a feature on Paypal's website. I want to get the address via IPN/PDT. Alternatives outside PayPal are useless to me, I already have those. Thanks for resp.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing.. as far as I can tell PayPal do not provide this information for some reason.. the only way I can think of is to add it as a value passed into the button settings

Comment: Yes, one solution is to send as `CUSTOM` parameter and writes into it any data, then such values ​​divided by `:` and re-use command `explode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal in the foreseeable future due to unknown reasons does not allow this feature. Probably the best solution is to send parameter `CUSTOM` and enter the necessary data into it, they are sent to PayPal and then back to the merchant's site. Payment order **must be dispatched from the merchant's site**, differently detect IP addresses will not be correct. Details [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

`CUSTOM` parameter is limited up to 256 characters.

**Send via GET method**

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=XY&custom=custom_string
```

**Send via POST method**

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="custom_string" />
```

**Callback data**

Callback is performed via `NOTIFY_URL` parameter. To the specified URL will be sent details of the transaction. `NOTIFY_URL` must be included in the configuration *Buy Now button* or URL link or default in the PayPal account.

Example URL link:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=XY&custom=custom_string&notify_url=http://site.com/pay.php
```

Data getting was performed via GET or POST method from PayPal site with array `$keyarray['custom']` (default). See details [here](https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples).